# How do I add data to msg.payload for sending via MQTT?

Tags: mqtt

I hope this isn't too basic, but I have two Raspberry Pi's.  On Pi#1, I have an object like this:

> { "payload":"on", "bri":100 }

But when I send this to Pi#2, the "bri" gets stripped off because MQTT only sends the payload value.  I'm certain there's something obvious that has escaped me, but a few hours of searching and experimenting hasn't gotten me any further.  How do I get both the payload of "on" and the brightness of 100 into a single payload so that MQTT will send both?

(Then I have to figure out how to retrieve the data for the light that's being controlled).

If anyone can help, I would truly appreciate it.

Comment: I believe Mqtt message is a string. Just stringify the json object.

Comment: You are missing some context here, I assume you mean with Node-RED?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, node-red on both Pi's.
In my search for a solution, I stumbled across a node called msgpack that has some promise.
But, my solution was to just send the bri value and on the receiving end, if the payload is zero, then the light is off.  If it's >0 then the light is on.
(I know this is breaking the rules, but thank you)